# How to calculate marginal effects, average partial effects in multinomial logit model of the form Y ~ 0 | X1 + X2 + X3

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model, data-transformation, multinomial-distribution

I am a doing research with a dataset of students to develop a model that predicts a course that is available for them.

the dataset

```
> head(data)
  id sex age matStatus ACCOUNTS AGRICULTURE ARABIC BIOLOGY C.R.E CHEMISTRY CLOTHING...TEXTILES ECONOMICS ENGLISH ENTERPRENUERSHIP F.ART FOOD...NUTRITION FRENCH  GEOGRAPHY GEOM...BUILD.DRAW GERMAN HEALTH.SCIENCE HISTORY I.R.E KISWAHILI LATIN LITERATURE MATH MUSIC PHYSICS SUB.MATHS TYPE.WRITING points lapse  gpa course
1 347   F  21         S     <NA>        <NA>   <NA>    <NA>     E      <NA>                <NA>         O    <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>   <NA>1         D              <NA>   <NA>           <NA>       D  <NA>      <NA>  <NA>       <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>      <NA>         <NA>     20    3  4.13    BSW
2 369   F  20         S     <NA>        <NA>   <NA>    <NA>     C      <NA>                <NA>         E    <NA>                O  <NA>             <NA>   <NA>2      <NA>              <NA>   <NA>           <NA>       D  <NA>      <NA>  <NA>       <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>      <NA>         <NA>     19    3  4.40    BBA
3  70   F  24         S     <NA>        <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>                <NA>      <NA>    <NA>             <NA>     E             <NA>   <NA>3         O              <NA>   <NA>           <NA>       O  <NA>      <NA>  <NA>       <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>      <NA>         <NA>     20    3  4.09    BBC
4 171   M  26         S     <NA>        <NA>   <NA>    <NA>     E      <NA>                <NA>         O    <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>   <NA>4      <NA>              <NA>   <NA>           <NA>       D  <NA>      <NA>  <NA>          D <NA>  <NA>    <NA>      <NA>         <NA>     19    3  4.10   BAMC
5 261   F  21         S     <NA>        <NA>   <NA>    <NA>     C      <NA>                <NA>         C    <NA>             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>   <NA>5      <NA>              <NA>   <NA>           <NA>       D  <NA>      <NA>  <NA>          D <NA>  <NA>    <NA>      <NA>         <NA>     17    3  4.58    BSW
6   9   F  20         S     <NA>        <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>                <NA>         D       B             <NA>  <NA>             <NA>   <NA>6         B              <NA>   <NA>           <NA>    <NA>  <NA>      <NA>  <NA>          C <NA>  <NA>    <NA>      <NA>         <NA>     23    4  4.68    LLB
```

I have run a 3 multinomial logit models

model1

```
> mldata <- mlogit.data(data, choice="course", shape="wide")
> mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(course ~ 1 | points +0, data=mldata, reflevel="BIFA")
> summary(mlogit.model1)

Call:
mlogit(formula = course ~ 1 | points + 0, data = mldata, reflevel = "BIFA", 
method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
 BIFA      BAED       BAL      BAMC      BASE       BBA       BBC      BCDM      BCEE       BCH       BCL       BCS        BD       BDS       BEM       BES 
 0.0276756 0.0273556 0.0020797 0.0588706 0.0124780 0.1522956 0.0350344 0.0139178 0.0028795 0.0108783 0.0046393 0.0033595 0.0102384 0.0814270 0.0430331 0.0049592 
  BGC      BLIS       BNS      BPAM      BPLM      BPPE      BSCS      BSIT       BSW      DEIT       DSW       LLB 
  0.0022396 0.0377540 0.0022396 0.0623900 0.0574308 0.0508719 0.0102384 0.0383939 0.1412574 0.0119981 0.0043193 0.0897456 

nr method
6 iterations, 0h:0m:17s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 7.13E-07 
gradient close to zero 

    Coefficients :
               Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
points:BAED  0.00022766  0.01066903  0.0213   0.98298    
points:BAL  -0.25187611  0.03045818 -8.2696 2.220e-16 ***
points:BAMC  0.08803382  0.00866528 10.1594 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BASE -0.07582578  0.01405080 -5.3965 6.794e-08 ***
points:BBA   0.15988826  0.00798943 20.0125 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BBC   0.03807751  0.00959833  3.9671 7.275e-05 ***
points:BCDM -0.06842869  0.01363999 -5.0168 5.255e-07 ***
points:BCEE -0.18975463  0.02305337 -8.2311 2.220e-16 ***
points:BCH  -0.09857204  0.01543601 -6.3858 1.704e-10 ***
points:BCL  -0.19118620  0.02320212 -8.2400 2.220e-16 ***
points:BCS  -0.20619712  0.02482144 -8.3072 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BD   -0.09948207  0.01549537 -6.4201 1.362e-10 ***
points:BDS   0.10235312  0.00847859 12.0719 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BEM   0.06673642  0.00900487  7.4111 1.252e-13 ***
points:BES  -0.15467348  0.01970383 -7.8499 4.219e-15 ***
points:BGC  -0.27729947  0.03409594 -8.1329 4.441e-16 ***
points:BLIS  0.01830602  0.01011328  1.8101   0.07028 .  
points:BNS  -0.33387449  0.04363818 -7.6510 1.998e-14 ***
points:BPAM  0.07548828  0.00885574  8.5242 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BPLM  0.07926952  0.00879553  9.0125 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BPPE  0.06266534  0.00907909  6.9022 5.122e-12 ***
points:BSCS -0.08560921  0.01462367 -5.8542 4.794e-09 ***
points:BSIT  0.04489153  0.00944166  4.7546 1.988e-06 ***
points:BSW   0.14106104  0.00811064 17.3921 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:DEIT -0.11014543  0.01621423 -6.7931 1.097e-11 ***
points:DSW  -0.23728979  0.02853729 -8.3151 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:LLB   0.15267625  0.00803211 19.0082 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -17155
```

model2

> mlogit.model2 <- mlogit(course ~ 1 | gpa +0, data=mldata, reflevel="BIFA")
>   summary(mlogit.model2)

```
Call:
mlogit(formula = course ~ 1 | gpa + 0, data = mldata, reflevel = "BIFA", 
    method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
     BIFA      BAED       BAL      BAMC      BASE       BBA       BBC      BCDM      BCEE       BCH       BCL       BCS        BD       BDS       BEM       BES 
0.0276756 0.0273556 0.0020797 0.0588706 0.0124780 0.1522956 0.0350344 0.0139178 0.0028795 0.0108783 0.0046393 0.0033595 0.0102384 0.0814270 0.0430331 0.0049592 
      BGC      BLIS       BNS      BPAM      BPLM      BPPE      BSCS      BSIT       BSW      DEIT       DSW       LLB 
0.0022396 0.0377540 0.0022396 0.0623900 0.0574308 0.0508719 0.0102384 0.0383939 0.1412574 0.0119981 0.0043193 0.0897456 

nr method
6 iterations, 0h:0m:17s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 2.35E-05 
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
           Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
gpa:BAED -0.0027701  0.0298693 -0.0927 0.9261081    
gpa:BAL  -0.7412647  0.0810757 -9.1429 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BAMC  0.1951123  0.0257518  7.5766 3.553e-14 ***
gpa:BASE -0.2198284  0.0376763 -5.8347 5.390e-09 ***
gpa:BBA   0.4586384  0.0229784 19.9595 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BBC   0.0529567  0.0284712  1.8600 0.0628839 .  
gpa:BCDM -0.1874346  0.0362355 -5.1727 2.308e-07 ***
gpa:BCEE -0.6293173  0.0677470 -9.2892 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BCH  -0.2348261  0.0383807 -6.1183 9.455e-10 ***
gpa:BCL  -0.4854006  0.0542648 -8.9450 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BCS  -0.6064262  0.0653467 -9.2801 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BD   -0.2579504  0.0395148 -6.5279 6.668e-11 ***
gpa:BDS   0.2997247  0.0243689 12.2995 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BEM   0.1128524  0.0271893  4.1506 3.316e-05 ***
gpa:BES  -0.4961531  0.0551472 -8.9969 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BGC  -0.7192712  0.0782362 -9.1936 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BLIS  0.0942808  0.0275640  3.4204 0.0006252 ***
gpa:BNS  -0.6963716  0.0753985 -9.2359 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BPAM  0.2231104  0.0253372  8.8056 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BPLM  0.1910022  0.0258157  7.3987 1.374e-13 ***
gpa:BPPE  0.1608714  0.0263084  6.1148 9.666e-10 ***
gpa:BSCS -0.2782549  0.0405603 -6.8603 6.872e-12 ***
gpa:BSIT  0.0712450  0.0280568  2.5393 0.0111069 *  
gpa:BSW   0.4416860  0.0230945 19.1252 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:DEIT -0.2542097  0.0393273 -6.4640 1.020e-10 ***
gpa:DSW  -0.5797138  0.0626741 -9.2497 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:LLB   0.3102902  0.0242526 12.7941 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -17626
>
```

models3

```
> mlogit.model6 <- mlogit(course ~ 1 | points + gpa +0, data=mldata, reflevel="BIFA")
> summary(mlogit.model6)

Call:
mlogit(formula = course ~ 1 | points + gpa + 0, data = mldata, 
    reflevel = "BIFA", method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
     BIFA      BAED       BAL      BAMC      BASE       BBA       BBC      BCDM      BCEE       BCH       BCL       BCS        BD       BDS       BEM       BES 
0.0276756 0.0273556 0.0020797 0.0588706 0.0124780 0.1522956 0.0350344 0.0139178 0.0028795 0.0108783 0.0046393 0.0033595 0.0102384 0.0814270 0.0430331 0.0049592 
      BGC      BLIS       BNS      BPAM      BPLM      BPPE      BSCS      BSIT       BSW      DEIT       DSW       LLB 
0.0022396 0.0377540 0.0022396 0.0623900 0.0574308 0.0508719 0.0102384 0.0383939 0.1412574 0.0119981 0.0043193 0.0897456 

nr method
8 iterations, 0h:0m:44s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 2.16E-07 
gradient close to zero 

Coefficients :
             Estimate Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
points:BAED  0.015998   0.040704   0.3930 0.6942869    
points:BAL   0.137131   0.101182   1.3553 0.1753248    
points:BAMC  0.411049   0.033764  12.1743 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BASE -0.054739   0.052708  -1.0385 0.2990280    
points:BBA   0.407890   0.031358  13.0076 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BBC   0.299277   0.036444   8.2119 2.220e-16 ***
points:BCDM -0.105206   0.051745  -2.0332 0.0420346 *  
points:BCEE  0.337325   0.076639   4.4015 1.075e-05 ***
points:BCH  -0.305404   0.059348  -5.1460 2.661e-07 ***
points:BCL  -0.328612   0.085359  -3.8498 0.0001182 ***
points:BCS   0.061859   0.085610   0.7226 0.4699483    
points:BD   -0.202919   0.058839  -3.4487 0.0005633 ***
points:BDS   0.195467   0.032617   5.9928 2.062e-09 ***
points:BEM   0.444982   0.035071  12.6880 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BES   0.180406   0.067990   2.6534 0.0079677 ** 
points:BGC  -0.262361   0.120231  -2.1821 0.0290999 *  
points:BLIS -0.170013   0.039760  -4.2759 1.903e-05 ***
points:BNS  -0.997998   0.148607  -6.7157 1.872e-11 ***
points:BPAM  0.120799   0.033997   3.5532 0.0003805 ***
points:BPLM  0.306090   0.033844   9.0443 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BPPE  0.197279   0.034708   5.6840 1.316e-08 ***
points:BSCS  0.081116   0.053305   1.5218 0.1280717    
points:BSIT  0.316662   0.035971   8.8032 < 2.2e-16 ***
points:BSW   0.192314   0.031250   6.1541 7.552e-10 ***
points:DEIT -0.374069   0.062417  -5.9931 2.059e-09 ***
points:DSW  -0.455851   0.102893  -4.4303 9.409e-06 ***
points:LLB   1.132841   0.042859  26.4318 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BAED    -0.042174   0.104653  -0.4030 0.6869541    
gpa:BAL     -1.090580   0.290828  -3.7499 0.0001769 ***
gpa:BAMC    -1.006031   0.095820 -10.4992 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BASE    -0.083650   0.131483  -0.6362 0.5246404    
gpa:BBA     -0.729323   0.084446  -8.6366 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BBC     -0.778534   0.103218  -7.5426 4.596e-14 ***
gpa:BCDM     0.065148   0.125923   0.5174 0.6049027    
gpa:BCEE    -1.585723   0.253598  -6.2529 4.029e-10 ***
gpa:BCH      0.444434   0.130489   3.4059 0.0006594 ***
gpa:BCL      0.249661   0.181169   1.3781 0.1681844    
gpa:BCS     -0.753821   0.231684  -3.2537 0.0011393 ** 
gpa:BD       0.211796   0.135818   1.5594 0.1188981    
gpa:BDS     -0.220331   0.086341  -2.5519 0.0107151 *  
gpa:BEM     -1.209072   0.102967 -11.7423 < 2.2e-16 ***
gpa:BES     -0.969412   0.198193  -4.8913 1.002e-06 ***
gpa:BGC     -0.109146   0.263636  -0.4140 0.6788706    
gpa:BLIS     0.482456   0.096055   5.0227 5.095e-07 ***
gpa:BNS      1.097557   0.211044   5.2006 1.986e-07 ***
gpa:BPAM    -0.089654   0.089202  -1.0051 0.3148619    
gpa:BPLM    -0.661655   0.093337  -7.0889 1.352e-12 ***
gpa:BPPE    -0.363799   0.093438  -3.8935 9.882e-05 ***
gpa:BSCS    -0.480201   0.143360  -3.3496 0.0008093 ***
gpa:BSIT    -0.815423   0.102078  -7.9882 1.332e-15 ***
gpa:BSW     -0.069997   0.081662  -0.8572 0.3913602    
gpa:DEIT     0.558586   0.132426   4.2181 2.464e-05 ***
gpa:DSW      0.399181   0.201819   1.9779 0.0479383 *  
gpa:LLB     -4.154221   0.168558 -24.6456 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -15647
>
```

however problems start with marginal effects with this error, what did i do wrong? my experience with R is not the best.

```
> #calculating the mean values for the variables
> z <- with(mldata, data,frame(points = tapply(points, index(mlogit.model6)$alt, mean),
 +                              gpa = tapply(gpa, index(mlogit.model6)$alt, mean)
+                              ))
> 
> 
> #marginal effects
> effects(mlogit.model6, covariate="points", data = z)
Error in predict.mlogit(object, data) : 
  the number of rows of the data.frame should be a multiple of the number of alternatives
>
```

I have 3 other questions

1. does this code really create an interaction or how do i include interactions

   mlogit.model4 <- mlogit(course ~ 1 | points * gpa * sex +0, data=mldata, reflevel="BIFA")
2. also how do I calculate average Partial effects for the categorical variables such as sex
3. Can Mixed effect models be used when subjects such as HISTORY CHEMISTRY ...  need to be included

thank you